# stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i write the following `stored procedure` but it gives error, how can i make it work properly. thanks.

```
/* stored procedure interestcalc writen by M */
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE PROCEDURE spInterestCal
 (
    @P_NO  INT,
    @TOTAL_MONEY   INT,
    @PAYMENT_TYPE  INT,  /* if payment type is 1 then Yearly, 2 then Semi Yearly, 3 then Quaterly, 4 then Montly  */
    @INTEREST_RATE  INT,
    @START_DATE  DATE,
    @END_DATE  DATE,
  )
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR FLOAT 
    DECLARE @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER INT
    DECLARE @INTEREST FLOAT 
    DECLARE @I INT
    DECLARE @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER INT
    SET @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR = 0
    SET @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 0
    SET @INTEREST = 0
    SET @I = 1
    SET @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 0

    /*
    DECLARE @YEARS_DIFF INT
    DECLARE @MONTHS_DIFF INT
    DECLARE @DAYS_DIFF INT
    SET @YEARS_DIFF = DATEDIFF(YYYY,@START_DATE,@END_DATE)
    SET @MONTHS_DIFF = DATEDIFF(M,@START_DATE,@END_DATE)-(datediff(YYYY,@START_DATE,@END_DATE)*12)
    SET @DAYS_DIFF = DATEPART(D,@END_DATE)-DATEPART(D,@START_DATE) 
    */

    IF (@PAYMENT_TYPE = 1)  /* if PaymentType is 1 means Yearly */
       BEGIN 
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR = 1;
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 1; /*Yearly So 1 INSTALLMENT */
       END

    IF (@PAYMENT_TYPE = 2)  /* if PaymentType is 2 means Semi Yearly */
       BEGIN
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR = 0.5;
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 2; /*Semi Yearly So 2 INSTALLMENT */
       END

    IF (@PAYMENT_TYPE = 3)  /* if PaymentType is 3 means Quaterly */
       BEGIN
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR = 0.25;
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 4; /*Quaterly So 4 INSTALLMENT */
       END
    IF (@PAYMENT_TYPE = 4)   /* if PaymentType is 4 means Montly  */
       BEGIN 
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR = 0.08;
            SELECT @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = 12;  /*Montly So 12 INSTALLMENT */
       END 

    SELECT @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = ((SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, @START_DATE, @END_DATE))* @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER)
    DECLARE @SMOUNT INT
    DECLARE @SYEAR INT
    SELECT @SMOUNT = (SELECT MONTH(@START_DATE))
    SELECT @SYEAR =  (SELECT YEAR(@START_DATE))

    WHILE ((SELECT @I) < = @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER )  /* Calculates Interest And Prints Info*/
        BEGIN
             IF (@SMOUNT > 12)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @SYEAR +1
                END
            SELECT @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER = @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER -1
            SELECT @INTEREST = ((SELECT @TOTAL_MONEY) - (SELECT @R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER * (SELECT @INSTALLMENT_FACTOR*(SELECT @TOTAL_MONEY)))) * ((SELECT @INTEREST_RATE)/100 ) 
            PRINT '  P_NO IS   ' + @P_NO + '  TOTAL_MONEY IS   ' + @TOTAL_MONEY + '  INSTALLMET AMOUNT IS   ' + @TOTAL_MONEY/@R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER +  ' @INTEREST IS  '+ @INTEREST  + ' DUE DATE IS  '+ (SELECT DAY(@START_DATE))  + '/' + (@SMOUNT) + '/' +(@SYEAR) 
            SELECT @SMOUNT = @SMOUNT + @INSTALLMENT_NUMBER-1

        END    

END
GO
```

Comment: what is the `error` you are getting ?

Comment: Remove the comma after the last parameter: `@end_date`

Comment: sorry but if you interested u can execute it and see. since sometimes the error messages do not give good info.

Comment: ok codingbiz yes your right i forgot bu then still i get warning. since your comment is useful i rated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be 4 errors when parsing your query - try parsing it yourself in SQL Server Management Studio and you will see:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 18
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 74
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 79
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

There also appear to be some logical errors which you will not be able to detect without fixing the above problems first.

To correct the first parsing error, simply remove the spurious comma from the end of your parameter list (noting the removed comma):

```
@END_DATE  DATE
```

The second error is also straight-forward, put `GO` after the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` and before `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
```

The next concerns your `PRINT` statement, which contains a `SELECT DAY(@START_DATE)` statement - this is not permitted and should be removed:

```
DAY(@START_DATE)
```

The final one is occurring because you have `END GO` on one line at the end of your procedure.  Try:

```
END
GO
```

Comment: By the way after i fixed the procedure and i put it on sql navigator (i have 5.5 version) it gives error but does not give error with microsoft sql server. why is it? thanks

Comment: when i try to execute this procedure it gives error spInterestCal P_NO = 999 , TOTAL_MONEY = 400 , PAYMENT_TYPE =  3, INTEREST_RATE = 10 , START_DATE = '2012-3-10' , END_DATE = '2014-5-12'    ps: because i couldn't sent the comment with @ sign i deleted the @ sign in front of each parameter

Comment: error is : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 70
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '  POLICY_NO   IS   ' to data type int.

Comment: Hi again @modestandcutegirl, sorry for the delay in responding.  This error is occurring on your `PRINT` line because you are mixing numeric and string data types.  You will need to `CAST` all of your numeric types to `VARCHAR` (or another `CHAR`) to fix this, example: `PRINT '  P_NO IS   ' + CAST(@P_NO AS VARCHAR) + ...`

Answer (score 1):

I see two syntax error:

1) *Incorrect syntax near ')'*. Remove the comma after the last paramter: `@END_DATE`

2) *Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed*

```
PRINT '  P_NO IS   ' + @P_NO + '  TOTAL_MONEY IS   ' + @TOTAL_MONEY + '  
   INSTALLMET AMOUNT IS   ' + @TOTAL_MONEY/@R_INSTALLMENT_NUMBER +  ' @INTEREST IS  '+ 
   @INTEREST  + ' DUE DATE IS  '+ 
   (SELECT DAY(@START_DATE))  + '/' + (@SMOUNT) + '/' +(@SYEAR)
```

Remove `SELECT` from `(SELECT DAY(@START_DATE))` and only have `' DUE DATE IS  '+DAY(@START_DATE) + '/'`

Comment: when i try to execute this procedure it gives error spInterestCal P_NO = 999 , TOTAL_MONEY = 400 , PAYMENT_TYPE = 3, INTEREST_RATE = 10 , START_DATE = '2012-3-10' , END_DATE = '2014-5-12' ps: because i couldn't sent the comment with @ sign i deleted the @ sign in front of each parameter –

Comment: error is : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spInterestCal, Line 70 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' POLICY_NO IS ' to data type int